# Debug electron-forge app with VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, electron, forge

I'm trying to debug my electron-forge project with VSCode (electron main process, not render) but getting erros everywhere. I installed `electron-forge` package with all dependencies and init my project.

I followed [this](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge#debugging-your-application-through-vs-code) instruction and my `launch.json` for VSCode was:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Electron Main",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron-forge-vscode-win.cmd",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I hit `F5` in VSCode to debug, I got `Attribute "runtimeExecutable" does not exist` because `electron-forge` is installed globally so there is no such file in `node_modules/.bin/` dir.

Then according to [this](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge-templates/issues/34) I changed `"runtimeExecutable"` and my `launch.json` was as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Electron Main",
            "runtimeExecutable": "electron-forge-vscode-win.cmd",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The comand line was:

```
electron-forge-vscode-win.cmd --debug-brk=17423 --nolazy 
√ Locating Application
√ Preparing native dependencies
√ Launching Application
```

But still nothig happened. My electron app started but didn't stop as `--debug-brk` argument supposed.

Next, I added one line to my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "name": "Electron Main",
            "runtimeExecutable": "electron-forge-vscode-win.cmd",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

Launched with this command line:

```
electron-forge-vscode-win.cmd --inspect=11172 --debug-brk 
√ Locating Application
√ Preparing native dependencies
√ Launching Application
```

*Note:* **11172** *is a random port number*

And now I'm getting this error: `Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:11172)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you need to add
`"protocol"="legacy"`
To your launch config. This is with the assumption that you are using a Node version < 8.x

Answer (score 4):

I've come to the conclusion that you cannot use VSCode to debug the main electron process if you use electron-forge or electron-compile. In both cases, the VSCode debugger ignores breakpoints. The BrowserWindow comes up directly and the following message appears in the VSCode debug console window:

```
Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is set.
c:\Users\paulk\OneDrive\dev\forge-debug/node_modules/.bin/electron.CMD --inspect=16988 --debug-brk .
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:16988/9cead160-c448-4b33-a8a2-2dff6f51ed59
```

Sometimes when I close the browser window, a breakpoint in the "close all windows" event handler is hit. After closing the window, the following message appears in the debug console:

```
Debugger attached.
```

Perhaps this indicates that the VSCode debugger does not attach until after the BrowserWindow closes.

I believe the problem originates with electron-compile, which eletron-forge uses. Perhaps it has something to do with compiling on the fly.

Use VSCode to debug a simple Electron app is a breeze. Further, plain Electron emits a different message in the debugger window:

```
Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is set.
c:\Users\paulk\OneDrive\dev\electron-quick-start/node_modules/.bin/electron.CMD --inspect=37884 --debug-brk .
Debugger listening on port 37884.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
```

This indicates that plain Electron is using a different method of connecting to the debugger than does electron-compile.

It is a shame that electron-forge does not work with VSCode main process debugging. This makes it useless for me. Also, the developers of electron-forge and electron-compile do not seem to consider this a problem. It would be helpful to know what debuggers the developers of electron-forge and electron-compile and the users of these packages are using to debug main process code.

Comment: Apparently this is a bug in the version of electron used by electron-prebuilt-compiled (1.8.2-beta 3). See https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/401#issuecomment-354369382.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `【"port": 11172】` in `launch.json` after protocol.

[image: my launch.json file]